# Databinder Eval value.value will not work

Tags: c#, sql, databinder

I'm testing databinds in ASP.NET with C# Visual Studio. But I've a irritating problem... To show all products from a database I use a repeater with a datasource query. The query is:

> SELECT titel, prijs, Product.artikelnummer, bestandnaam FROM Product INNER JOIN (Foto INNER JOIN Productfoto ON Foto.[foto_id] = Productfoto.[foto_id]) ON Product.[artikelnummer] = Productfoto.[artikelnummer] ORDER BY titel;

Because artikelnummer exist in multiple tables, I must write the table name before it. But when I'll load the data in a repeater, single names work, like:

> DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "bestandnaam")

But when I use the "**artikelnummer"**:

> DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Product.artikelnummer")

I get a error: *DataBinding: 'System.Data.Common.DataRecordInternal' does not contain a property with the name 'Product'.*

How could I read the artikelnummer? It is important for me because the product_detailview will load his data from the article number(artikelnummer in dutch)

Anyone??

Answer (score 2):

If you have multiple names that are the same in your SQL output (select portion), use an alias to separate them:

```
SELECT titel, prijs, Product.artikelnummer as Productartikelnummer, bestandnaam FROM Product INNER JOIN (Foto INNER JOIN Productfoto ON Foto.[foto_id] = Productfoto.[foto_id]) ON Product.[artikelnummer] = Productfoto.[artikelnummer] ORDER BY titel;
```

However, I only see *artikelnummer* being returned once so you shouldn't have a problem using it.

```
DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "artikelnummer")
```

The result set will automatically remove the 'Product.' portion for the column name, so you can't perfix your column names with the table name in the binding method.